# Name cannot begin with the ' ' character in jquery if else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am just trying to check the window width and based on the width I change some values using jQuery.

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
var windowsize = $(window).width();

    if (windowsize < 480) {
      //DO SOMETHING          
        });


    } 
else {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }

});
</script>
```

I'm receiving the following error:

`Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 365, position 28`

Only the `if else` condition having the error.

Comment: I am not JQuery person but in my point of view `nextText:'';` cannot resolve try changing `nextText:' ';` simple put a blank space within it;

Comment: In ehi h line do you get the error?

Comment: just edit the code.actually the bxslider script has no problem.the issue with the if condition.if I change to > then it work.means ( if(windowsize > 480){}) then it will working.I can't understand what is the issue with if(windowsize < 480){}

Comment: You've either missed some code under the do somthing line or you have an extra `});`

Comment: `});` shouldn't be after `//Do Something` Fix your code example  to be more accurate or if this is your codes current state it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra commas after the last parameter in both cases, and it looks like you have unprintable characters as well.

Delete the trailing commas, clean up the whitespace, and you should be good.

Like this:

```
    moveSlides: 1
});
```

Comment: There is no problem.actually the problrm with if condition.I just edit the question.please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect `});`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();

    if (windowsize < 480) {
      //DO SOMETHING          //  }); // here no need to close this 
    } else {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an incorrect `)};` closing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var windowsize = $(window).width();
    if (windowsize < 480) {
      //DO SOMETHING          
        } else {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You should try indenting your code so that the brackets line up

I've altered your code so that it outputs to the `console` for each of the `if` conditions. This is giving me the expected results whenever I call it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    if (windowsize < 480) {
        console.log('less than');
    } 
    else {
        console.log('greater than');
    }

});
```